# Geoserver: SQL-View for layer creation ignores PostgreSQL array_agg function

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I am running Geoserver 2.11.2 running on Tomcat 7 on a Win7 64bit system, PostgreSQL 9.6.

I am trying to create a parametric view for layer creation like this

```
SELECT 
%FOO% AS thing,
array_agg(id) AS ids,
array_agg(name) AS names 
FROM 
settings
WHERE
%FOO% IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
%FOO%
```

However the only attribute showing up is 'thing'.
When using another aggregate function (for example string_agg) instead of array_agg like this

```
SELECT 
    %FOO% AS thing,
    string_agg(id,',') AS ids,
    string_agg(name,',') AS names 
    FROM 
    settings
    WHERE
    %FOO% IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
    %FOO%
```

everything works fine with all attributes (thing,ids,names) showing up as expected. What is going on here? Does the term 'array' have to be escaped/aliased in some sort of way?

Comment: turn debugging up to developer and try again, the actual query used will be in the log file

Comment: Convert the arrays to text

Comment: @iant : thanks for the hint, but I'm afraid the log in debug mode does not show the resulting queries. I don't really know why that is, maybe debug mode properties have to be tweaked.

Comment: @ziggy : that actually did the trick, thank you! Do you want to maybe post this as an answer I will then accept?